Linux module command setup via xrdp or x2go
I have the 'module' (lmod) command set up on my Ubuntu Linux servers. This works well for users who connect via ssh to the server ('module avail' shows the available modules). Some users want to connect using xrdp or x2go, and when they open a terminal window in that type of session, the 'module' commands don't work.
I can solve this on a case-by-base basis by having them edit the preferences in the terminal app and setting 'Run command as a login shell'. New terminal sessions after that will have the 'module' environment set up correctly.
How can I set this system-wide, so that all users get that 'login shell' behavior? Or, how can I configure it so that the lmod setup gets run whether it's a login shell or not?
